# The indexed page number decrease after migrating from http to https

Tags: https, migration

My website is migrating from http to https, but both http and https URL can work.
The indexed page number in https increase, but decrease in http.

Why does the indexed page number in http decrease? Is it normal?

Comment: Yes. Thais how it works. You are no longer using HTTP so the number of pages indexed decreases and you are now using HTTPS and so the number increases.